# Is it possible to get a notification when there's a key eviction from a cache application

Tags: caching

memcached, redis, varnish, ...

Is there a way to check thousands and thousands of keys every second to verify they were not evicted from the cache ?

Is there a specific cache application for such purpose ?

I don't think it would be possible to scale that way... but correct me if I am wrong.

Are there cache apps or modules that can send you a notice when a key is evicted ? That would probably make more sense.

Comment: Why do you even care if a key is evicted?  It's just cache.

Comment: Because my keys have a timeout and unless they are re-updated, they get evicted when they reach the time limit. I want to know when a key hits that limit. As I will have 50k+ keys at all times and want to know when one is evicted I though of caching as a fast mechanism. If you have a better idea, I am all ears!

Comment: Why do you want to know when a key hits that limit?

Comment: They are all "timers" going down to zero unless they are re-initialized (time speaking). Every time one reach zero, I want to be able to perform an action for that very specific key. Let say I want to create a file with the key's name.

Comment: It doesn't sound like that's a cache at all, but something else entirely.  You want to have a collection of timers that count down?

Comment: Yes, as I said I am all ears. It's more of a hack then actually a standard cache as I don't know any system type designed for my needs. Maybe Node.js as it is asynchronous...

Comment: Yes, I think it would be best to go back to the drawing board.  Something much more standard like a priority queue or async callbacks would work better.  Node.js would work as well as anything else (you could write this in any reasonable language/environment).